# wr new printwriter *bw( error). Program gets basic info form user (id,name last name.) However still getting that error. Any idea?

Tags: java, arraylist

i am using the following code:

```
package Presentacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class RegistroUser {

    String Nombres, Apellidos, id, dia, mes, ano, s, ce, df, celu, RH;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<List<String>> lista = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    public List<List<String>> getlista() {
        return lista;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getLista() {
        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<List<String>> Lista) {
        this.lista = Lista;
    }

    public void Columna() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            lista.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }

    }
```

when i try to use the function >

```
public void Escribir(String registro) {

        File f;
        FileWriter w;
        BufferedWriter bw;
        PrintWriter wr;
        try {
            f = new File(registro);
            w = new FileWriter(f);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(w);
            wr = new printwriter(bw);
            wr.write("Su lista es:");
            wr.println();
            wr.println();

        } 


        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error en el momento de crear el archivo" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

i am getting the error " cannot find symbol" Symbol: class printwriter.

```
 wr = new printwriter(bw);
```

The rest of the code is:

```
 public void adddata() {

        System.out.println("Digite Nombres del usuario:");
        Nombres = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(0).add(Nombres);
        System.out.println("Digite Apellidos del usuario:");
        Apellidos = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(1).add(Apellidos);
        System.out.println("Digite Numero de  identificacion del  usuario:");
        id = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(2).add(id);
        System.out.println("Fecha de Nacimiento del  usuario:");
        System.out.println("Digite el dia");
        dia = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(3).add(dia);
        System.out.println("Digite el Mes");
        mes = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(3).add(mes);
        System.out.println("Digite el Año");
        ano = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(3).add(ano);
        System.out.println("Escriba el sexo del usuario M o F");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(4).add(s);
        System.out.println("Escriba direccion  fisica del usuario");
        df = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(5).add(df);
        System.out.println("Escriba direccion de correo electronico del usuario");
        ce = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(6).add(ce);
        System.out.println("Escriba numero telefonico");
        celu = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(7).add(celu);
        System.out.println("Escriba RH del usuario");
        RH = sc.nextLine();
        lista.get(8).add(RH);
        System.out.println("\n");

    }

    public void showdata() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.get(0).size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("  %15s", lista.get(0).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s         ", lista.get(1).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s          ", lista.get(2).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s     ", lista.get(3).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s        ", lista.get(4).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s        ", lista.get(5).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s", lista.get(6).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s", lista.get(7).get(i));
            System.out.printf("%15s", lista.get(8).get(i));
            System.out.println("\n");

        }
    }

    public void deletedata() {
        lista.get(0).remove(lista.get(0).size() - 1);
        lista.get(1).remove(lista.get(1).size() - 1);
        lista.get(2).remove(lista.get(2).size() - 1);
        lista.get(3).remove(lista.get(3).size() - 1);
        lista.get(4).remove(lista.get(4).size() - 1);
        lista.get(5).remove(lista.get(5).size() - 1);
        lista.get(6).remove(lista.get(6).size() - 1);
        lista.get(7).remove(lista.get(7).size() - 1);
        lista.get(8).remove(lista.get(8).size() - 1);
    }

    public void listsize() {
        System.out.println(lista.get(0).size());

    }

    public void clearlist() {
        lista.get(0).clear();
        lista.get(1).clear();
        lista.get(2).clear();
        lista.get(3).clear();
        lista.get(4).clear();
        lista.get(5).clear();
        lista.get(6).clear();
    }

    public void checklist() {
        if (lista.get(0).size() < 0) {
            System.out.println("No hay informacion en lista");
        } else {
            System.out.println("La lista contiene " + lista.get(0).size() + " Datos ");
        }


    }


}
```

Any idea why am i getting this error_
 Program gets basic info form user (id,name last name.) However still getting that error. Any idea?

Comment: Java is a case-sensitive language. `printWriter` and `printwriter` are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Java is case-sensitive:
Instead of:

```
wr = new printwriter(bw);
```

use:

```
wr = new PrintWriter(bw);
```